# Getting issue in selecting element based on title using xpath

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

[image]

**My Xpath** : `((//span[text()='Number of Allowances'])/../../../following::div//table[@class='mainTable']//tr[1]//input[@data-automation-id="numericInput" ])`

In above xpath I have clearly specified that I want to select text box which is just below of title **Number of Allowances** though it is showing me more than one text boxes as evaluation.

As I don't want to pass index to select element , I have wrote above xpath to select exact text box which is below particular title but seems I am missing something.

Comment: do you have the page soure?

Comment: @johnII - Yes but its too lengthy. Does it require to share?

Comment: well we really cannot figure it out unless we can see the source

Comment: If you don't show us your XML, at least the relevant portions, it would be difficult to answer your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Let me share Html source.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - source is too lengthy and SO has limit for characters :(

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the number of preceding TD's is the same as the number of TD's preceding hte "Number of Alowances"?

Comment: You don't have to (and shouldn't try to) post the entire HTML.  Instead, carve out the critical parts -- create a [mcve].

Comment: @choroba - for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the following toy table:

```
<html>
<head><title>T</title></head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
      <td>col4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td input="1">val1</td>
      <td input="1">val2</td>
      <td input="1">val3</td>
      <td input="1">val4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

For a heading, the corresponding input must have the same number of preceding `td` siblings, so for example for `col3`:

```
//td[@input]
    [count(preceding-sibling::td)
     =count(../../tr/td[.="col3"]/preceding-sibling::td)]
```

Tested in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh).